# Eclipse debugging : Stack trace on event

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Im trying to get the code flow of an open source platform. I have got the source code and ran the program from eclipse. The program has an option called "Run job" and I want to know where the control goes when that option is clicked. How can achieve this?

Comment: Did you compile the application from source code or are you running it from provided libraries( jars)?

Comment: From the source code downloaded using svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from searching for the appropriate handlers and buttons in the source code (if you know the names), you can also enable tracing.

In your run configuration, there should be a tab for tracing. There, you'll want to enable some of the options under `org.eclipse.ui` that start with `trace/`.

[image: Screenshot on how to enable tracing]

You will get *a lot* of debug output, and there might be no trace option for the event you'd like to see. However it works well for things like keybindings (`trace/keyBindings`) and knowing which UI element got an event (`trace/graphics`). Note that some also take arguments, e.g. a commandId (something like `org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy`, will depend on your application).

You can find a small help text for each option [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/bundles/org.eclipse.ui/.options).

Answer (score 2):

First, try to identify the control with the label "Run job".

You could do this by searching the source code in Eclipse with `Search` > `File` and then setting "Containing Text" to "Run job" and "File name patterns" to "*.java".

Probably in the same file, there is an ActionListener (or similar) added to the control that calls a method, when the control is clicked. This is the method you're looking for. (Add a breakpoint to see the flow in the debugger or try to understand it from the code.)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't really help me. I was just giving an example--  I may have to detect flow of other events as well, like click , drag and drop event and this will not work then.

Comment: Then your question seems quite general to me and can't be answered.